# How to use react-icons with select-option form element?

Tags: reactjs, react-icons

I would like to know if it is possible use react-icons with the select-option elements. I google a lot about the problem but all the solutions were related to react-select library rather than the simple select-option elements.

here's what i am doing

```
import {ReactIcon} from "react-icons";
.............
 some code here
.............
<select> 
    <option> sometext <ReactIcon /> </option>
   <option>  sometext <ReactIcon /> </option>
</select>
```

**result:**

```
sometext [Object object]
sometext [Object object]
```

**what I want:**

```
sometext {the icon itself}  
sometext {the icon itself}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Only strings and numbers are supported as `<option>` children. Hence the icon is not rendering.

You need to use a React Select Component such as [react-select](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-select). This works well with [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons/icons?name=ai).

A working example with the above-mentioned components:

```
import Select from "react-select";
import {
  AiFillAlert,
  AiFillAlipayCircle,
  AiFillContainer
} from "react-icons/ai";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
  // The label supports JSX.
  const options = [
    {
      value: "chocolate",
      label: (
        <div>
          <AiFillAlert /> Chocolate
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      value: "strawberry",
      label: (
        <div>
          <AiFillAlipayCircle /> Strawberry
        </div>
      )
    },
    {
      value: "vanilla",
      label: (
        <div>
          <AiFillContainer /> Vanilla
        </div>
      )
    }
  ];

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Select value={selectedOption} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The above code renders the following component:
[image]